# Error:(18, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'android()' compile

Tags: java, eclipse, android-studio, gradle, compiler-errors

I am new to Android and Android Studio so, I downloaded a project that I also need for my class then I got this error. I could not find my answer here, although there was a question like mine. Please help me to run this program that I downloaded from internet and solve this error, thank you.

These are my gradles:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.gettaxi"
    minSdkVersion 8
    targetSdkVersion 17
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.0'
}
```

And:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.stackoverflow.answer"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),     'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    }
}
```